# LED bulb with slow on motion detector

Tags: electrical

Can an LED bulb be used with a retarded on motion detector? Incandescent bulbs come on slowly with this type of detector to extend the lamp life.

---

These are externally mounted on an electrical box to control the fixture. I replace a couple every year on this house. It's an ocean front house and there are a lot surges because of weather. 
The ones I've bought the last couple of years don't snap on instantly but act though turned on with a rheostat. Before I blow a 1000 bucks on LEDs I would like to know if an LED would work with this type of motion detector. 
They also have a dusk on feature where the incandescent lamps are partly on. How are they affected with that feature. 
My experience is as a Navy Construction Electrician mostly with power generation and distribution and telephone exchanges. Telecom and data cabling systemsand business telephone equipment is my civilian business

Answer (score 1):

That's a cool idea but Google won't show me any commercial products like that, outside of commercial lighting intended for displays.  Are you quite sure this actually exists?  Make/model maybe?  I'm wondering if it's actually the lamp doing that for some reason.

It would not help extend LED life but would make them more pleasant. Look at the documentation and see what it says about working with LEDs, that is to say, there are several methods of dimming, which one does it use?  Get compatible "dimmable LEDs" and you should be fine. Even if they are not compatible, they'll come on when it ramps to full brightness.

Comment: Compatibility probably means buying dimmable LED bulbs in this case.

Comment: Yeah.....dimmable LED bulbs....if the fixture really does support the "soft on" feature. I've not seen those around.